# populate combobox from the selected item of other combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm creating a form in which a user has to give a State name and a City name. Where the city depends on the state.

Code for populating the city:

```
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql As String
   sql = "SELECT * from statestab order by `state` ASC;"
   adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
   adapter.Fill(ds)
   ComboBoxstate.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
   ComboBoxstate.ValueMember = "stateid"
   ComboBoxstate.DisplayMember = "state"
```

Code for the city :

```
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql As String
Dim st As Integer
   st = ComboBoxstate.SelectedValue.ToString()
   sql = "SELECT * from citytab where stateid=st  order by `cityname`  ASC;"
   adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
   adapter.Fill(ds)
   citycombo.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
   citycombo.ValueMember = "cityid"
   citycombo.DisplayMember = "cityname"
```

In the combobox, when the selected city is changed, I call the city load function to populate the city combobox.
But I'm cant populate the city combobox.

Comment: What is not working? You get an error or the states just don't show up?

Comment: It _looks_ like you're not passing in the state ID into your 2nd query, just the text `"st"` rather than the value of the `st` variable.  Unless you have a column in that table called `st`, I would expect you to be seeing a SQL exception?

Comment: i have a column name stateid in city tab , which is also present statestab

Answer (score 0):

You will need handler in Selected_Index_Changed in your State Combobox. From there call your routine to load up the City, in the SQL for city you would need to do

```
where stateid=" & comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is full text, Note that is can be much better but I tried to keep your syntax in tact:

```
 Private Sub cboState_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboState.SelectedIndexChanged
    Load_Cities()

End Sub

Private Sub Load_States()
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT * from tblState order by StateName ASC;"
    adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    cboState.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    cboState.ValueMember = "stateid"
    cboState.DisplayMember = "statename"
End Sub

Private Sub Load_Cities()
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT * from tblCity where StateID = " & cboState.SelectedValue.ToString() & " order by CityName ASC;"
    adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    cboCity.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    cboCity.ValueMember = "CityID"
    cboCity.DisplayMember = "CityName"



End Sub
```

Comment: thanks i  added  StateID = " & cboState.SelectedValue.ToString() this to my code and it is working like charm